# Counter-example of a non-selfadjoint operator for which $ \left\| T \right\|= \sup_{x\in \mathcal{H},\left\| x \right\|=1} |(Tx,x)|$ does not hold.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, self-adjoint-operators

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hilbert space and $T \in \mathcal{L(H )}$,  if $T$ is selfadjoint, then we have : 
$$   \left\| T \right\|= \sup_{x\in \mathcal{H},\left\| x \right\|=1} |(Tx,x)|$$
I want a counter-example of a non-selfadjoint operator for which the equality given above does not hold.

Answer (score 1):

Let $T$ be given by

$$T=\begin{pmatrix}
      0 & 1\\
       -1 & 0
    \end{pmatrix}.$$

Then $T$ is a non- selfadjoint operator on the real Hilbert space $\mathbb R^2$ (with the usual inner product).

We have $(Tx,x)=0$ for all $ x \in \mathbb R^2.$

Answer (score 1):

The canonical example is  $$A=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\in M_2 (\mathbb C). $$ You have  $\|A\|=1$, while $|\langle Ax,x\rangle|\leq\frac12\,\|x\|^2$ for all $x\in\mathbb C^2 $.